# Passing two arguments in Dispatcher.Invoke

Tags: wpf, vb.net, dispatcher

I am trying two update UI from another thread:

```
Me.Dispatcher.Invoke(Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, New Action(AddressOf RefreshDisplay))
```

The problem is that I need t0 pass two arguments to ***RefreshDisplay***

```
Private Sub RefreshDisplay(ByVal n1 As String, ByVal n2 As String)
 .
 .
 .
 .
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a delegate type that matches the target method.  That can't be Action, that's a delegate for a method that takes no arguments.  Fix:

```
    Me.Dispatcher.Invoke(Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, _
                         New Action(Of String, String)(AddressOf RefreshDisplay), _
                         "foo", "bar")
```

Don't forget to actually pass those two arguments, I of course had to guess at them.